# Adding JSON and JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Please check attached files, I can't add the JSON file to JavaScript, and the student information from JSON file is empty. 
I included the HTML, CSS, JS, and JSON file below to easily view or copy into notepad++
The JSON file is directly below JavaScript so it has to be moved.

When I run this in a browser it doesn't show errors but the student information is empty.

```js
// Wait until the page loads.
window.onload= function(){
    // Read JSON data and display to page.
    processData();
}; 
// Read the student JSON string, convert it to a JavaScript object.
function processData() {
    ajaxLoadFile('students.json', function(response) {
         // Convert JSON string into JavaScript Object.
         let jsResponse = JSON.parse(response);
         // Display the results
         displayData(jsResponse) ;
    });
}
// Display the student data.
function displayData(students) {
    // Add the student data to the DOM.
    
    // Hide the loading message.
}

/**
 * Description: Loads a file from the web server.  Runs a callback function if sucessfull.
 * Parameters:  filename    The filename to load.
 *              callback    The callback function to run after the file has been loaded.
 */
function ajaxLoadFile(filename, callback) {
    // Create new request.
    let xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    // Add datetime parameter to the URL to prevent browser caching.
    let bustCache = '?datetime=' + new Date().getTime();
    xobj.open('GET', filename + bustCache, true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // 4 == DONE, 200 == request was fulfilled.
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            // File was loaded so run callback function.
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    }
}

//JSON file is as follows.
{
"students":[
{
"First name": "Amin",
"Last name": "Mohammad",
"Favorite subject in school": "Science",
"Favorite hobby": "Video Gmaes",
"Favorite color": "Green"
},
{
"First name": "Larry",
"Last name": "Hansley",
"Favorite subject in school": "Math",
"Favorite hobby": "Soccer",
"Favorite color": "White"
},
{
"First name": "John",
"Last name": "Ceana",
"Favorite subject in school": "English",
"Favorite hobby": "Wrestling",
"Favorite color": "Green"
},
{
"First name": "Shaun",
"Last name": "Goave",
"Favorite subject in school": "Hstory",
"Favorite hobby": "Football",
"Favorite color": "Red"
},
{
"First name": "Carry",
"Last name": "Green",
"Favorite subject in school": "Math",
"Favorite hobby": "Walking",
"Favorite color": "Blue"
}
]
}
```

```css
    body {
    background: transparent url('https://chelan.highline.edu/~tpollard/assets/images/tri.svg') top center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #555;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    border-bottom: 0.02em solid #3f87a6;    
    color: #3f87a6;
}

.loading {
    background: transparent url('https://chelan.highline.edu/~tpollard/assets/images/ajax-loader_trans.gif') center left no-repeat;
    color: #94aace;
    font-size: smaller;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.loadingHidden {
    display: none;
}

main {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 60vh;
    max-width: 40em;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2em #ccc;
    padding: 2em 5% 3em 5%;
    margin: 0 ;
    display: flex-container;
}

section {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.student-info p {
    background: transparent url('https://chelan.highline.edu/~tpollard/assets/images/user_grayscale.png') center left no-repeat;
 padding-left: 20px; 
}

@media (min-width: 45em) {
    main {
        width: 80%;
        padding: 2em 5% 6em 5%;
        margin: 4em ;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>AJAX Example</title>
    <meta name="description" content="This is a simple example using AJAX">
    <meta name="author" content="Amin Mohammad">

    <!-- link to external CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Content of the page goes here. -->
    <main>
        <h1>Use AJAX to Read a JSON file</h1>
        <section class="intro">
            <h2>Introduction</h2>
            <p>In this assignment you will use AJAX to read in an external JSON data file. 
                You will convert this external JSON data file into a JavaScript object and 
                then display the contents in a web page. 
            </p>
        </section>

        <section class="student-info">
            <h2>Student Information from JSON file</h2>
            <p class="loading">Loading student data...</p>
        </section>
    </main>

    <!-- link to external JS file -->
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
   
 
</body>
        
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One statement is missed in function ajaxLoadFile() `xobj.send()` just before the close of the function.

Chrome and IE does not allow to access JSON file from local system. 
In Firefox, the file is read.